# Approaches to calculating the determinant of a general $n\times n$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Matrix we're trying to calculate the determinant of

[image: Matrix we're trying to calculate the determinant of]

Been kind of stuck on trying to find an expression for the determinant of this matrix. I've tried to diagonalize the matrix by doing a series of row operations that technically would not affect the determinant and managed to simplify the matrix a lot but not quite get to a clear diagonal form. Any hints or ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix